# Consulta php y función mail problema con hotmail

Tags: php, html

Estoy aprendiendo, desarrollando un carrito de compras. Mi problema es que tengo un form de registración con activación por mail.

Funciona correctamente, pero claro, siempre lo había probado con mi cuenta de gmail. Cuando un usuario se registra , le envío un mail con un link de "activar mi cuenta" , ese link contiene la ruta de mi archivo activar.php y le paso una clave para que valide en la base. En hotmail sale el texto del link pegado a "activar mi cuenta" , o sea no se ve como link.
Hice un pastebin del código que envía el correo, agradeceré ayuda para mejorarlo.

http://pastebin.com/evzWVEzD

```
function mailActivacion($dir_correo, $usuario){

    global $url;
    $tipocorreos=explode('@',$dir_correo);
    if ($tipocorreos['1']=='gmail.com'){
    //para el envío en formato HTML
    $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";
    $headers .= 'From: Bureau de Regalos <info@bureauderegalos.com>' . "\r\n" .
    $headers .= 'Bcc: busca2011@gmail.com' . "\r\n";
    "Reply-To: remitente@dominio.com" . "\r\n";
    "X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion();
    $destinatario = $dir_correo;
    $asunto = 'Activación de Usuario';
    $cuerpo = '
   <strong>Solo falta 1 paso ...</strong>;
   <h2>Hola';
    $cuerpo .= " " . $usuario;
    $cuerpo .= '</h2><strong>Gracias por registrarte en nuestro Sitio.</strong><br />Para completar el registro tienes que confirmar que has recibido este email, haciendo click en el siguiente enlace :
   <p style="text-align: center;">';
    $cuerpo .= '<a href=' . $url . '>Activar mi Cuenta</a>';
    $cuerpo .= '</p>';    
    }else{
    //para el envío en formato HTML
    $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";
    $headers .= 'From: Bureau de Regalos <info@bureauderegalos.com>' . "\r\n" .
    "Reply-To: remitente@dominio.com" . "\r\n" .
    "X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion();
    $destinatario = $dir_correo;
    $asunto = utf8_decode('Activación de Usuario');
    $cuerpo = '
   <strong>Solo falta 1 paso ...</strong>;
   <h2>Hola';
    $cuerpo .= " " . $usuario;
    $cuerpo .= '</h2><strong>Gracias por registrarte en nuestro Sitio.</strong><br />Para completar el registro tienes que confirmar que has recibido este email, haciendo click en el siguiente enlace :
   <p style="text-align: center;">';
    $cuerpo .= '<a href=' . $url . '>Activar mi Cuenta</a>';
    $cuerpo .= '</p>
   ';      
    }
    mail($destinatario,$asunto,utf8_decode($cuerpo),$headers);
```

Comment: Sería mucho mejor que pegaras las partes relevantes de tu código aquí. De esta manera, si por algún motivo el link fallara, la pregunta no perdería su validez.

Comment: Ok gracias , ahí copié el código q utilizo.

Comment: Puede ser por la liberación de la variable, trata de encerrar todo en comillas dobles en ves de simples...

Comment: @Cig - como pueden fallar las comillas dobles y simples en este caso? No lo veo...

Comment: @aldanux tienes una representación de como se ve el link, una imagen?

Comment: @Cig - tendrás que preguntar al OP -> look68 no a mi... yo te pregunto: que como se soluciona si lo cambias todo a doble comillas... la syntax es válida... lo único que veo que le faltan comillas en el atributo `href` en elemento `<a>`...quizás sea eso que homtail no lo interpreta bien... pero lo dudo...

Comment: Hola , me di cuenta del problema xque tengo la web en desarrollo y se registró un amigo q tiene hotmail, me mandó una captura x whatsapp del error. Básicamente sería lo siguiente :

Comment: perdon se me fue el enter .

En hotmail muestra :

[www.misitio.com.ar/activar.php?id=Wqhgs2]Activar mi Cuenta

Comment: Encierra el vínculo con [ ]

Comment: @look68 - pon comillas en tu elemento `<a href="">`, que se quede así: `$cuerpo .= '<a href="' . $url . '">Activar mi Cuenta</a>';`....prueba a ver

Comment: gracias aldanux ... pero sigue saliendo igual , acabo de dar de alta un hotmail para hacer las pruebas y obtuve el mismo resultado, vaya a saber x que motivo me convierte el href a una cadena sin vínculo .. y me agrega los corchetes [ ]  ..

Comment: Bueno, al final , a diferencia de gmail, hotmail necesita que le especifique en la variable el http://  .... no lo podía creer , ya funciona. Muchas gracias !!

Comment: Creo que tu amigo ve una versión en texto plano del correo, podría ser un problema del cliente de correo, deberías probar con más gente.